# Conditional fields in contact form 7 not working

Tags: javascript, plugin-contact-form-7

In my contact form I need a drop down for order quantities. On selection of "other", I want to display a number field for input. Below is my code but it's not working. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("OrderQuantity").addEventListener("change", displayNumberField);
  function displayNumberField() {
    var dropDownText =  document.getElementById("OrderQuantity").value;
    if (dropDownText == "Other") {
      document.getElementById("EnterOtherQuantity").style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("EnterOtherQuantity").style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>

<label> Order Quantity
[select* drop-down-menu id=OrderQuantity "Select Quantity" "10" "20" "30" "40" "Other"] </label>

<label id="EnterOtherQuantity" style="display:none;"> Please Specify Your Order Quantity
[number other-order-quantity min:41] </label>
```

Comment: you can do that with this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Tom. I have to do this using java script. Any suggestions about above code?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this add-on to make conditional fields.
https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/

Answer (score 0):

Note that **[select* drop-down-menu id="OrderQuantity"]** CF7 shortcode will not output any id for the select, so you cannot use *document.getElementById* but you can rely on the name attribute:

```
<label> Order Quantity
[select* drop-down-menu id=OrderQuantity "Select Quantity" "10" "20" "30" "40" "Other"] </label>

<label id="EnterOtherQuantity" style="display:none;"> Please Specify Your Order Quantity
[number other-order-quantity min:41] </label>

[submit "Send"]

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByName("drop-down-menu")[0].addEventListener("change", displayNumberField);

function displayNumberField() {
  var dropDownText =  document.getElementsByName("drop-down-menu")[0].value;
  if (dropDownText == "Other") {
    document.getElementById("EnterOtherQuantity").style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("EnterOtherQuantity").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function show_hide_field(qt) {

    qt=="6"?document.getElementById("div-qt-other").style.display="block":document.getElementById("div-qt-other").style.display="none";
}
</script>

Comment: Order Quantity:
<select name="test" onchange="show_hide_field(this.value);">
    <option value="1">---Select Quantity---</option>val
    <option value="2">10</option>
    <option value="3">20</option>
    <option value="4">30</option>
    <option value="5">40</option>
    <option value="6">Other</option>
</select>

Comment: <div class="form-group" id="div-qt-other" style="display:none;">
<br>
<label class="control-label" for="order-quantity-other" style="color:#2842da;">Please Enter Other Quantity [number other-order-quantity min:41] </label>
</div>